# Why storing objects addresses in a buffer causes a memory leak when instantiating and deleting them?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, new-operator, delete-operator

I'm working on a Windows environment with Visual Studio 2013.
In my application, I need to store the addresses of the `new`-ly created objects.

Something simple as this allocates ~7.6MB of memory and deallocates them as expected, program starts with memory usage ~0.4MB:

```
double* dptr = new double[1000000]; // allocates 8*1000000 ~7.6MB
delete[] dptr;
```

after the last line, memory usage goes back to 0.4MB.

But the problem occurs when I try to do something like this:

```
// addresses buffer for objects of type 'double'
double** dpptr = new double*[1000000];

// instantiate objects and store their addresses in the buffer
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    dpptr[i] = new double;
/**** Problem 1 ****/

// --- time passes ---

// delete each object
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    delete dpptr[i];

// delete the addresses buffer
delete[] dpptr;
/**** Problem 2 ****/
```

On my machine `sizeof(double*)` = 4 and `sizeof(double)` = 8, so if I'm doing the maths correctly:

- Size of the addresses buffer = 4 * 1000000 ~3.8MB
- Size of all `double` objects = 8 * 1000000 ~7.6MB
- Total memory usage should be 11.4MB

But when i run this program I face 2 problems:

1. Before deleting each object (after instantiating them), the memory usage goes up to ~72.9MB rather than 11.4MB
2. After the last line, memory usage goes down to ~6.1MB rather than 0.4MB as stated above.

Why is this causing a huge memory usage over the expected ?

Also what's the reason of the memory leak at the end of the program ?

Comment: "after the last line, memory usage goes back to 0.4MB." Post an actual program that illustrates this. Programs do not hand memory back  to the operating system, they hand it back to the memory allocator (which might, but probably won't hand it back to the OS).

Comment: You probably cannot allocate just 8 bytes, but will always allocate at least 16, if not more.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth All the memory usage values are captured from TaskManager during a debugging session, so it may of course be different on your machine.
Do you think I should mention that in the post ?

Comment: I think you don't understand how memory is allocated  and reclaimed. Generally, memory allocated to a process is not returned to the OS until the process terminates.

Comment: @Kerrek SB but in the first example "new double[1000000]" actually allocated 7.6MB as expected

Comment: Yes, 7.6MB is bigger than 8B, so you can allocate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Dynamic memory allocations have overhead. The overhead is proportionally larger for small allocations. 8 bytes is quite a small individual allocation. (If implemented with `malloc`) Dynamic memory allocations must be aligned to the largest native alignment. That is 16 bytes on my system. That would explain a minimum of 100% overhead for an 8 byte allocation. There will be some bookkeeping overhead as well to keep track of all allocations. The amount of bookkeping information is proportional to the number of allocations - which is much greater in your latter example than in the former. I'm not sure if this explains all of your memory use, but 11.4MB is certainly an unrealistic expectation.
2. There probably was no memory leak. More likely just your expectation that the process would release the memory to the operating system was simply misguided. The memory allocation provided by the runtime library is typically implemented so that it often doesn't release the memory. This is especially likely for small deallocations, and deallocations that weren't done in LIFO order - although whether either has an effect will depend on the implementation.

   The allocation system keeps the freed memory for the process, and reuses it for future allocations. To see if there really was a leak, repeat the allocations and see if the memory use doubles from the previous.